# Change Button Color in a GridView on Load in Wpf Application

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a telerik radgridview with buttons in the grid,on clicking it I set a flag
in the database.I want to know how to change color of button according to flag on loading .Is there any way to get the buttons and use them in a condition. This is a WPF application.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your button indicates a flag so i guess ToggleButton is the best solution for you.
You can style its "VisualStateManager" on "IsChecked" condition, and also bind the "IsChecked" property to the relevant data.